# Django folder permissions for installation

Tags: django, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

The official Django installation documentation seems to be lacking in exactly how to set up folder permissions post-installation so that a 403 Foridden error does not show up on a live apache installation.

I've spent 2 months going through thousands of forum posts, hundreds of guides, and countless Stackoverflow Q&As about setting up folder permissions. No single two of these posts, guides or Q&As are the same. All are riddled with users having to implement custom solutions here and there to get things working, there's no consistency anywhere as to exactly what folder permissions should be set up. I probably speak for silent untold thousands who gave up when trying to do folder permissions.

So my question is simple, how do I set the correct file and folder permissions on Ubuntu 16.04, configured with Python 2.11 in a virtual environment, with Django on an Apache mod_wsgi server?

My structure is as per the official documentation - /home/main/myproject/project
All of these folders (home, main, myproject and project) have 755 permissions owned by a non-root sudo user called 'main' which I use for everything.

I've done:

```
chmod 664 ~/myproject/db.sqlite3
chmod 775 ~/myproject
sudo chown :www-data ~/myproject/db.sqlite3
sudo chown :www-data ~/myproject
```

Apparently these are all the permissions I need. Yet I still get a 403 forbidden error. How on earth do I please get this Django thing live?

Edit: I've followed this tutorial exactly: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-apache-and-mod_wsgi-on-debian-8 particularly the part with appending /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

My 000-default.conf append looks like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
. . .

Alias /static /home/main/myproject/static
<Directory /home/main/myproject/static>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

# Next, add the following directory block
<Directory /home/main/myproject/project>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>

WSGIDaemonProcess project python-home=/home/main/myproject/projectenv python-path=/home/main/myproject
WSGIProcessGroup project
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/main/myproject/project/wsgi.py
```

My Apache error logs don't seem to show any issues after visiting the forbidden domain index:

[Wed Jun 27 07:03:46.807525 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 21287] AH00171: 
Graceful restart requested, doing restart
[Wed Jun 27 07:03:46.878042 2018] [wsgi:warn] [pid 21287] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/2.7.11.
[Wed Jun 27 07:03:46.878052 2018] [wsgi:warn] [pid 21287] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/2.7.12.
[Wed Jun 27 07:03:46.878142 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 21287] AH00163: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) mod_fcgid/2.3.9 OpenSSL/1.0.2g mod_wsgi/4.3.0 Python/2.7.12 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Jun 27 07:03:46.878156 2018] [core:notice] [pid 21287] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Wed Jun 27 07:03:50.444008 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 21287] AH00171: Graceful restart requested, doing restart
[Wed Jun 27 07:03:50.517693 2018] [wsgi:warn] [pid 21287] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/2.7.11.
[Wed Jun 27 07:03:50.517704 2018] [wsgi:warn] [pid 21287] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/2.7.12.
[Wed Jun 27 07:03:50.517823 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 21287] AH00163: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) mod_fcgid/2.3.9 OpenSSL/1.0.2g mod_wsgi/4.3.0 Python/2.7.12 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Jun 27 07:03:50.517837 2018] [core:notice] [pid 21287] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'

Comment: At a first glance, your permissions look fine. Show us your apache configuration and server logs, if you can.

Comment: What makes you think this has to do with folder permissions?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Everything I read about this error seemed to indicate it was some lack of permission in a file or folder somewhere for apache. I'm completely open to any solution though.

Comment: Hang on, who is the user here? You've put it in `~/myproject`, but what user is `~` referring to? Why are you putting it in a home directory at all?

Comment: The user is 'main'. The ~/myproject is for the home directory of 'main'. Perhaps I missed something fundamental, I've just followed the DigitalOcean tutorial as exactly as I could since the official Django tutorial is lacking in details in this regard. I also read somewhere django projects should not be placed in the public_html folder as they should be kept separate outside of live Internet access. I honestly have no idea

Comment: Yes I can see the user is "main", but Apache will not be running as that user. So naturally it will not have access to that user's home directory. Don't put it under /home at all - I like to create a /srv directory off the root and put things in there. Make sure the www-data user has rights to that.

Comment: If you are getting a 403 Forbidden error from Apache, you should see in the Apache error log of the form ``client denied by server configuration`` or ``(13)Permission denied: access to / denied``. It is important to know which as it points at the issue. Since you don't see such an error, are you sure it isn't your Django code which is generating the 403 Forbidden message?

Comment: Set ``LogLevel info`` in your Apache configuration and it will show whether the WSGI script is being loaded. If it is, it means it is getting past Apache and is more likely your Django code generating it.